# How to center image inside grid col?

Tags: css, html, center

I'm using Bootstrap grid system and displaying one image in each col, but I didn't succeed to center the image vertically & horizontally. Here is my code:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .center_image {
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      .vcenter {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- images section  -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="display: flex; padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
        <!-- image col1 -->
        <div style="background-color: red;" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 vcenter">
          <img style="width: 100%;"
               class="img-responsive center_image img-thumbnail" alt=""
               src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701">
        </div>
        <!--image col2 -->
        <div style="background-color: red;" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 vcenter">
          <img class="img-responsive center_image img-thumbnail"
               style="width: 100%;" alt=""
               src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When `margin:auto;`, that's mean it should be equal from every side. right? but why the image didn't center horizontally?

Comment: solved with flexbox , least css used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use flex box to achieve this like :

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .center_image {
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      .vcenter {
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- images section  -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="display: flex; padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
        <!-- image col1 -->
        <div style="background-color: red;" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 vcenter">
          <img style="width: 100%;"
               class="img-responsive center_image img-thumbnail" alt=""
               src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701">
        </div>
        <!--image col2 -->
        <div style="background-color: red;" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 vcenter">
          <img class="img-responsive center_image img-thumbnail"
               style="width: 100%;" alt=""
               src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: They specifically asked for grid though, not flex box.

Comment: @iPzard the OP mention Bootstrap grid system which is based on flexbox, however this wasn't the core of the question

Comment: Oh, I see. It looks like he has "display: flex" on the row class too. My bad.

Answer (score 6):

To center something through `margin: 0 auto;`

The image or div must have a defined width.

For example, in your CSS, try this:

```
.center_image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but in this way it wont be responsive

Comment: @david sorry about that

Comment: Just `margin: auto;` should do the trick. Also, do not set both width and height for the image. Set either width *or* height.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use simple html center tag:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col'>
     <center>
        <img src='path' />
     </center>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked for me easily! Bravo

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    .vcenter {
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;

 -ms-flex-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 align-items: center;
      }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- images section  -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="display: flex; padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
        <!-- image col1 -->
        <div style="background-color: red;" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 vcenter">
          <img style="width: 100%;"
               class="img-responsive center_image img-thumbnail" alt=""
               src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701">
        </div>
        <!--image col2 -->
        <div style="background-color: red;" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 vcenter">
          <img class="img-responsive center_image img-thumbnail"
               style="width: 100%;" alt=""
               src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```